# Ruby Metaprogramming : How to print local variable by and class variable defined instide constructor

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am learning metaprogramming and trying to solve puzzle given here http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/Exercise_1.html

```
class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22
    a = 33
  end
  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end

Given the above class i have to print below ouptput

1
2
3
11
22
33
```

I am not able to print 33 and 3 . 
Can anyone help me in printing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this gist: https://gist.github.com/greggawatt/8994520

```
$results = []

$results << class A
  def initialize
    @a = 11
    @@a = 22
    a = 33
  end
  @a = 1
  @@a = 2
  a = 3
end
```

here we use `instance_variable_get` to return the value of the given instance variable and `class_variable_get` to retrieve the values of class variables.

```
$results << A.instance_variable_get(:@a)
$results << A.class_variable_get(:@@a)

puts $results.sort!

# 1
# 2
# 3

class B < A
  def initialize
    $results << super
  end
end


A.new
# define class A and get the instance variable 11 from the initialize method
$results <<  A.new.instance_variable_get(:@a)
# define class A and get the instance variable 22 from the initialize method
$results <<  A.class_variable_get(:@@a)

# here class B inherits from class A and use the `super` to call the `initialize` method of the parent class A, 
# this way you can retrieve the instance variable `a = 33` from the initialize method on Class A.
B.new

puts $results.sort!

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 11
# 22
# 33
```